# Android: How to set a stop flag in native C thread from Java

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-code

In my NDK Android app, Java part runs native C code to perform intensive calculations. It does so by creating an AsyncTask worker object that runs the native code in a separate thread via the JNI. The Java GUI has a stop button and the native code has a variable which is used as a stop flag to abort a lengthy calculation.

How do I set the stop flag in the native code, running in a separate thread, when the stop button is pressed in the main GUI thread?

Comment: You can call another JNI function when you press the button. That function will stop the C thread. Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess my question boils down to: How can I access a C variable (in my case a stop flag) from the main Java thread?

I tried setting up a JNI function, and called it within the onCancelled() method of AsyncTask is invoked (I overwrote onCancelled()), but that didn't work, i.e. the stop flag was not set in the native code.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java GUI Stop button should make a (separate) native call, which will set the (global C) stop flag. Your approach to override `AsyncTask.onCancelled()` cannot work as intended, because the AsyncTask is busy in its native code, and ignores a Java interrupt.

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean), `onCancelled()` will be invoked on the UI thread after `doInBackground()` responds to interrupt and returns.

Comment: Of course the native flag should be volatile.  If there can be more than one instance *in the entire process* that needs to be able to independently utilize this mechanism, then it also needs to be associated with the instance, rather than being static.

Comment: Thank you, that completely fixed it. Indeed, instead of calling the JNI stopping function from the AsyncWorker's onCancelled() method, I call it directly from the main UI thread (the part which handles the button press). This immediately sets the flag and stops the native code from running. Thanks again Alex, you were very helpful.

Comment: Hi Chris Stratton, thanks for your comment. I re-read it, and yes currently the native code can only be invoked in a single instance of the AsyncTask worker. The native stop flag is just a C int which is a global variable in the library. I'm not sure how I would define it as volatile in that context. Nevertheless, I'm curious to know how one would implement this scheme if a number of instances of the AsyncTask worker were to be called.

Comment: If there are many instances of native code invoked through AsyncTask, but cancel button is expected to stop all at once, the current approach is still fine. If you need control over which one to stop, you need multiple flags. If you want to stop only one, but don't care which, you need signal.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works, but I don't understand why it works, and therefore am not sure if it is safe.

I redefined the onCancelled() method of AsyncTask so that it calls a JNI function that sets the stop flag in the native code:

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled(String result){
    setCancelFlag(1);  //calls a JNI function that sets a stop flag in C  
    return;
}
```

When the stop button is pressed in the main thread, I handle that event as follows:

```
mAsyncWorker.cancel(true);
mAsyncWorker=new AsyncWorker(); //where AsyncWorker is a subclass of AsyncTask
mAsyncWorker.cancel(true);
unFreezeUI();// make the UI responsive
```

Essentially, if I invoke the cancel method of the worker, create a new instance of the worker and then re-invoke the cancel method on the new instance, I get the desired behavior, i.e. the thread stops and the UI becomes responsive again. If I don't instantiate a new worker and cancel it, the thread keeps running. If anyone knows why this is happening I'd be very grateful if you could explain it.

Comment: Ouch!  This seems to be based on abusing the native code's lack of distinction between instances to cover for misunderstanding of how the cancellation mechanism works.  Rather than doing this (which is really horrible) make a cancellation method with an original name and use that.  But beware that it will cancel every instance in the process (so make it a static method for clarity)!  Otherwise you need to tie the native flag to an instance.

Comment: Yes I was never happy with this solution. Fortunately, as Alex pointed out, the JNI function that sets the flag should be called directly from the main UI thread, not in the background thread (I had it in the onCancelled() method).
Since I am now accessing the native code asynchronously, I hope that this new method is safe. Of course, the stop flag is never modified within the native code.